# Excel sort with formula in cell

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-formula

When I have a formula in a cell (the list is about 8,000 long, I go to try and sort it from most to least, however when I do this it will not sort, I believe it is because there is a formula in the cell, is doing it the normal way of clicking on the cell(s) and using the ribbon. Is there a special way of doing it when a formula is involved?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by using absolute reference in your formulas, i.e. "`$`" for the rows. Since you are changing the order of the rows when you filter you need to make the reference static.

The table below is sorted by "Largest to smallest."

[image]

---

Another solution could be to copy the area and paste in a new sheet as "values"

Comment: This is so simple, I can't believe I didn't figure this out myself!! Thank you, you saved me a lot of stress!! Lol

Comment: No problem!! Glad to help. Please mark this question as accepted (grey check-mark below voting buttons) so other people can see that this question is solved :)!! Thanks.